# State give incorrect result

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have question regarding **state** result, it gives me strange result.
Here is the code

```
...
const initState = {
  count: 0
}

const counterReducer = (state=initState, { type }) => {

  switch (type) {
    case 'INCREMENT':
      return {    
        //i will get NaN if 
        //count: state.count + 1      

        // i  will get 1
        count: initState.count + 1 

      }

    default:
      return {
        state
      }
  }
}

const store = createStore(counterReducer);
console.log(store.getState());// here is 0

store.dispatch({ type: 'INCREMENT'})
console.log(store.getState()); //here is 1
...
```

I am confused with the result counterReducer, in the switch block, why if i put

```
count: state.count+1 //Why the result is **Nan**?
```

shouldn't it be 1? but if I put

```
count: initState.count+1
```

will have result 1

Appriciate for any help

Answer (score 1):

you have an error on your return, you are returning

```
{ state }
```

That means that you will create a new object with the property state, so the result will be like:

```
state: {
  state: {
    count: 1
  }
}
```

Change the return to

```
default:
      return state
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the state you have named is called `initState` Right on the top. and in the reducer cases you are accessing that state not `state`. Rename `initState` to whatever you like and do `whateveryoulike.count+1` and it will work.

Comment: It is strange, if we see the chaining of state is correct, for example initState is assigned to state, so the value state.count is 0 so when we count: state+1 should be 1. Sorry, your answer still make me curios